# Google Cloud Functions deploy failed with status code 51

Tags: google-cloud-functions

My javascript cloud function project keeps prompting error with status code 51 while deployment. The same error also occurred before yesterday, and it could succeed only if I rerun the deploy script a few times, but it never succeeded again since yesterday morning. I did nothing to modify my project.

The following are both scripts for start and deploy, `start` can always run correctly if I run `yarn start` or `npm run start`.

```
"start": "rm -rf dist && prettier -w src && npm run build && cp env.yaml clearmylist-46738ea42bf9.json package.json dist/ && cd dist && npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=clearMyList",
"deploy": "rm -rf dist && prettier -w src && npm run build && cp env.yaml clearmylist-46738ea42bf9.json package.json dist/ && gcloud functions deploy clear-my-list-google-cloud-functions --gen2 --runtime=nodejs18 --region=us-central1 --source=dist --entry-point=clearMyList --trigger-http --env-vars-file env.yaml --allow-unauthenticated --project clearmylist && rm -rf dist"
```

And the following are the latest error logs of running `yarn deploy`, anybody have such experience to solve this issue or give me some clues? Any help would be very appreciated!

```
{
  insertId: "1115fbbf-200b-4f2a-bef6-b9460b46d1de-509"
  labels: {
    build_step: "Step #1 - "build""
    build_tags: "p-gcf,r-nodejs18,v-nodejs18_20230416_18_15_0_RC00,b-nodejs_20230417_RC00"
  }
  logName: "projects/clearmylist/logs/cloudbuild"
  receiveTimestamp: "2023-04-27T11:01:53.867184869Z"
  resource: {
    labels: {
      build_id: "1115fbbf-200b-4f2a-bef6-b9460b46d1de"
      build_trigger_id: ""
      project_id: "clearmylist"
    }
    type: "build"
  }
  severity: "INFO"
  textPayload: "Step #1 - "build": ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1"
  timestamp: "2023-04-27T11:01:53.430315151Z"
}
```

```
{
  insertId: "1115fbbf-200b-4f2a-bef6-b9460b46d1de-512"
  labels: {
    build_step: "MAIN"
    build_tags: "p-gcf,r-nodejs18,v-nodejs18_20230416_18_15_0_RC00,b-nodejs_20230417_RC00"
  }
  logName: "projects/clearmylist/logs/cloudbuild"
  receiveTimestamp: "2023-04-27T11:01:55.839983449Z"
  resource: {
    labels: {
      build_id: "1115fbbf-200b-4f2a-bef6-b9460b46d1de"
      build_trigger_id: ""
      project_id: "clearmylist"
    }
    type: "build"
  }
  severity: "INFO"
  textPayload: "ERROR: build step 1 "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/gae-runtimes/gcp/buildpacks/google-gae-22/nodejs/builder:nodejs_20230417_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 51"
  timestamp: "2023-04-27T11:01:55.575842005Z"
}
```

Would Google Cloud Functions provide more detailed and precise information in building logs?

Comment: I started having this issue today as well. Totally random, nothing changed in the code.

Comment: Just found out that they're having some issues under Europe. I think this is also affecting the US, they just didn't update there. https://status.cloud.google.com/index.html

Comment: @LeonardoBarbosa, yes, I checked the Google Cloud Service Health before, all my deployments are in the US, and the `Americas (regions)` always shows `Available`, so I just assume the service is OK.

Comment: This can be related with their latest release, on the 25th. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#36300_2021-11-02

Comment: @LeonardoBarbosa, the latest update of `Cloud Functions` in release logs is https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#42600_2023-04-11, according to its description, I removed the `--gen2` parameter from my `deploy` script, and I got the same issue with code 51. My latest successful deployment is at UTC time "2023-04-25T16:03:34.433303997Z", so I believe `--gen2` doesn't matter.

Comment: More info on the issue (https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/dS9ps52MUnxQfyDGPfkY):
```
Description: Water intrusion in a data center in europe-west9 caused a multi-cluster failure that led to a shutdown of multiple zones. We expect some unavailability in the europe-west9 region. There is no current ETA for full recovery of operations in the europe-west9 region at this time. We expected to see an extended outage for some services. Customers are advised to failover to other regions if they are impacted.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if water intrusion in europe-west9 (Paris, France) would impact my deployment in Iowa USA, but this really makes me feel funny and possible :D Thank you @LeonardoBarbosa , I'll wait for a few days for further progress.

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't related. They're still having this issue, but my build is back working with the answer I posted. Hopefully it works for you, bud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google recently made some changes on their build process. From their words:

> For more context about this, recently we’ve made a change in our 1st and 2nd gen GCF for our NodeJS users (which I’ve noticed is your runtime, kindly correct me if I’m mistaken), where we automatically run the npm run build command during deployment if you had defined an npm build script in your package.json file. You may find more about this in our Release Notes for April 11st [1].

The fix here is to do one of these two things:

#### 1 - Add `--set-build-env-vars GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS=""` on the deploy script for your Cloud Function:

```
gcloud functions deploy <function-name> --set-build-env-vars GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS=""
```

or...

#### 2 - Add `"gcp-build":""` in your `package.json` file:

```json
{
  ...
  "gcp-build":"",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you add "gcp-build" as one of the "scripts" in `package.json`

Comment: Thank you @LeonardoBarbosa, both of them work for me :D And I choose to keep the gcp-build one.