# Python Google Cloud Function fails build with non-zero status: 51

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

Similar to this nodejs issue: [Google Cloud Functions deploy failed with status code 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76119694/google-cloud-functions-deploy-failed-with-status-code-51) , I am seeing the same exact issue in my python cloud functions.

This is quite random, and I have been able to validate the same exact the terraform works in a different project, on the same network / serverless connector.

I am in us-east4, and utilizing my enterprise proxies on the build config. This is literally a hello world script.

Any ideas / thoughts would be extremely helpful. Below is the full error.

```
"ERROR: build step 1 "us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/gae-runtimes/gcp/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:python_20230807_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 51"
```

While the logs on the cloud function are:

```
│ Error: Error waiting to create function: Error waiting for Creating function: Error code 3, message: Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: requesting https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu2204/python/python-3.10.12.tar.gz: Get "https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu2204/python/python-3.10.12.tar.gz": GET https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu2204/python/python-3.10.12.tar.gz giving up after 4 attempt(s): Get "https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu2204/python/python-3.10.12.tar.gz": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 10.165.144.81:8080: i/o timeout. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-east4/30c16d78-5744-4f86-bfcb-db6f63b90c79?project=747822733487.
│
│   with module.service_account_strategy.google_cloudfunctions2_function.function["us-east4"],
│   on ../../modules/sa_key_strat/main.tf line 142, in resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function":
│  142: resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
│
```

Here is the terraform that works in one project, but does not work in the other.

```
data "google_project" "current" {
  project_id = var.app_project_id
}

data "google_storage_bucket" "upload_bucket" {
  name = "gcf-v2-uploads-${local.project_number}-us-east4"
}

locals {
  project_number = data.google_project.current.number
  upload_bucket  = data.google_storage_bucket.upload_bucket.name
}



resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "object" {
  name   = "hello-world.zip"
  bucket = local.upload_bucket
  source = "hello-world.zip"
}

resource "google_service_account" "runtime" {
  account_id   = "testing-func"
  display_name = "Test SA - used for the cloud function."
  project      = var.app_project_id
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "invoking" {
  project = var.app_project_id
  role    = "roles/editor"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.runtime.email}"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  location    = "us-east4"
  project     = var.app_project_id
  name        = "testing-functions"
  description = "Platform services test deployment, safe to delete."

  build_config {
    runtime     = "python311"
    entry_point = "hello_get"
    environment_variables = {
      HTTP_PROXY              = "OUR PROXY",
      HTTPS_PROXY             = "OUR PROXY",
      NO_PROXY                = "grc.io,pkg.dev"
    }
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = local.upload_bucket
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.object.name
      }
    }
    worker_pool = module.cloudbuild_worker_pool_strat.worker_pool_id
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count             = 3
    min_instance_count             = 1
    available_memory               = "4Gi"
    timeout_seconds                = 60
    ingress_settings               = "ALLOW_INTERNAL_AND_GCLB"
    vpc_connector                  = "projects/<SHARED PROJECT>/locations/us-east4/connectors/serverless-priv-dev-ue4"
    vpc_connector_egress_settings  = "PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY"
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = true
    service_account_email          = google_service_account.runtime.email
  }

}


output "function_uri" {
  value = google_cloudfunctions2_function.function.service_config[0].uri
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as the error falls on line `142` in the `main.tf` file before being deployed on GCF?

Comment: Is it only today? It seems to be an internal error, and Tuesday is the usual rollout day of Google Cloud. Might be a broken update.

Comment: Hey Guillaume, still seeing the issue. Same network, same serverless connector, etc as another project. I attached the code being used in both projects above.